# Use Column and Row Multi-Index values in Pandas Groupby without unstacking

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-index hierarchy set up as follows:

```
import numpy as np

sectors = ['A','B','C','D']
ports = ['pf','bm']
dates = range(1,11)*2
wts, pchg = zip(*np.random.randn(20,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dates=dates,port=sorted(ports*10),
                       sector=np.random.choice(sectors,20), wts=wts,
                       pchg=pchg))

df = df.set_index(['port','sector','dates'])
df = df.unstack('port')
df = df.fillna(0)
```

I'd like group by `dates` and `port` , and sum `pchg` * `wts`

I've been through the docs but I'm struggling to figure this out.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? Because I don't fully get how you see the grouping by `dates` and `port` (as it is in a different axis). Is `df.product(axis=1, level=1).groupby(level='dates').mean()` what you want?

Comment: Hi @joris thanks for looking at this. The output should be the same as (in this case) `df.stack(port).groupby(level=[1,2]).apply(lambda x: (x['wts']*x["pchg"]).sum()).unstack('port')` if that makes sense. In practice I have a number of other columns that stop be taking the stack - unstuck round trip and would like to avoid the processing overhead too. You're right I'm trying to `groupby` on two axes at once.

Comment: Well, I think my suggestion does exactly that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed do not need to unstack to get what you want, using the `product` method to do the multiplication you want. Step by step:

Starting from this dataframe:

```
In [50]: df.head()
Out[50]:
                  pchg                 wts
port                bm        pf        bm        pf
sector dates
A      1      0.138996  0.451688  0.763287 -1.863401
       3      1.081863  0.000000  0.956807  0.000000
       4      0.207065  0.000000 -0.663175  0.000000
       5      0.258293 -0.868822  0.109336 -0.784900
       6     -1.016700  0.900241 -0.054077 -1.253191
```

We can first do the `pchg * wts` part with the [`product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.product.html) method, multiplying over axis 1, but only for the second level:

```
In [51]: df.product(axis=1, level=1).head()
Out[51]:
port                bm        pf
sector dates
A      1      0.106094 -0.841675
       3      1.035134  0.000000
       4     -0.137320  0.000000
       5      0.028241  0.681938
       6      0.054980 -1.128174
```

And then we can just group by `dates` (and no grouping by port needed anymore) and take the sum:

```
In [52]: df.product(axis=1, level=1).groupby(level='dates').sum()
Out[52]:
port         bm        pf
dates
1      0.106094 -0.841675
2      0.024968  1.357746
3      1.035134  1.776464
4     -0.137320  0.392312
5      0.028241  0.681938
6      0.054980 -1.128174
7      0.140183 -0.338828
8      1.296028 -1.526065
9     -0.213989  0.469104
10     0.058369 -0.006564
```

This gives the same output as

```
df.stack('port').groupby(level=[1,2]).apply(lambda x: (x['wts']*x["pchg"]).sum()).unstack('port')
```

Comment: Thanks @joris. I'll go away and try and figure out the logic. This is impressively concise. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @joris, sorry for the naive question , but can you explain why you're usine mean and not sum? I can't get my head around that part. Thanks..

Comment: Ah, that is a good question! I think because I made a mistake and it has to be `sum`, reading your question again. And indeed, it has to be `sum` to get the same output (the first line is just the same by accident). Edited the question!